# Java access modifiers - method available to subclasses and package

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Which access modifiers which when used with the method makes it available to all the class and subclasses within a package?

Comment: Probably some basic book about Java won't be extra one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`public`, `protected` and the default modifier (which doesn't have a keyword). Everything except `private`.

For example, suppose the package `foo` has the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
   public void method1() { };
   protected void method2() { };
   void method3() { };
   private void method4() { };
}
```

Then a class `foo.SecondClass` could call the methods `method1`, `method2` and `method3`, but not `method4`.

See the [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for a useful table of what each modifier allows.

Answer (score 2):

**Everything except private** (eg public, protected and the default modifier).
See the following image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package access modifier is actually the absence of a modifier.  it is also referred to as the 'default' modifier.  See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Access_Modifiers) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `protected` is actually less "protected" than saying nothing. Both the default *package-private* and `protected` allow access from within the package; `protected` then adds visibility to subclasses outside the package. It is more "protected" than `public` though.